# SQL query to return whether two strings contain a shared term

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a simple way to verify in an SQL query whether two string values from different columns share a term?

For example:

```
Str1 = "little brown fox" Str2 = "big brown bear" Return_Value = 1
Str1 = "Sun is shinning" Str2 = "Its raining" Return_Value = 0
```

Comment: Not sure, using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 if it helps

Comment: You can create a stored procedure to get a data from one row, split in the space character, and then do a LIKE in other row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probabbly isn't the best user function but this might help you down the path of what you need.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ContainsSharedTerm]
( @SearchString1 varchar(255), @SearchString2 varchar(255) )
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MatchFound BIT
    SET @MatchFound = 0
    DECLARE @TempString VARCHAR(255)

    WHILE LEN(@SearchString1) > 0 AND @MatchFound = 0
    BEGIN
        IF CHARINDEX(' ',@SearchString1) = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @TempString = @SearchString1
            SET @SearchString1 = ''
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @TempString = LEFT(@SearchString1,CHARINDEX(' ',@SearchString1)-1)
            SET @SearchString1 = RIGHT(@SearchString1,LEN(@SearchString1)-CHARINDEX(' ',@SearchString1))
        END

        IF CHARINDEX(@TempString,@SearchString2) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @MatchFound = 1
        END
    END
    RETURN @MatchFound
END

CREATE TABLE #TestTable (
    Col1 VARCHAR(100),
    Col2 VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO [#TestTable] ([Col1],[Col2]) VALUES ('little brown fox','big brown bear')
INSERT INTO [#TestTable] ([Col1],[Col2]) VALUES ('Sun is shinning','Its raining')

SELECT [Col1],[Col2],dbo.[ContainsSharedTerm]([Col1],[Col2]) AS [Match]
FROM [#TestTable]

DROP TABLE [#TestTable]
```

Comment: Once I have figured how to add this to the DB it worked great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You might have to do some modifications to the strings you are comparing but I would recommend looking at the CONTAINS function

Example:

```
WHERE
CONTAINS('little brown fox', 'big OR brown OR bear') OR 
CONTAINS('Sun is shinning', 'Its OR raining')
```

You can read more about CONTAINS here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Comment: For some reason it won't allow the second parameter to be a column too, so I can't run CONTAINS(Tbl1.Str1, Tbl2.Str2) , anyway to go around this?

Comment: Please note that you cannot used the CONTAINS function on a column which is not full-text indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but with PostgreSQL this would something like this:

```
select count(*) from (
  select unnest(string_to_array('little brown fox', ' '))
  intersect
  select unnest(string_to_array('big brown bear', ' '))
)  t
```

will return the number of words that match between both strings (so 1 for the above example and 0 for your second example)